# I can't extract Json because of byte order mark (BOM) - JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I am trying to extract a json variable from a response data in JMeter. But my response json is starting with a byte order mark so it is not recognized as a valid one. Here's my response json's starting part:

```
ï»¿{"error":false,"errorCode":null,"message":"","statusCode":200,"data":{"bigSlider":[{"displayOrder":0,"imageUrl":"https:\/\/6rk3rbju.rocketcdn.com\/image\/banner\/shopping-image\/0108slider-tartismasiz-app.jpg","link":{"t.......
```

Once I remove that "ï»¿" from the beginning of the response, I am able to extract json variables. But since I have to process the response with a post-processor in JMeter, I have written a script like this:

```
def BOM = "ï»¿"
def responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
if (responseData.startsWith(BOM)) {
    responseData = responseData.substring(1)
}
prev.setResponseData(responseData.getBytes('UTF-8'))
```

But doing this didn't help me but changing the BOM into something different like "Â»Â¿"

Could you please help me?

Comment: For removing the BOM it's safer to operate on bytearrays instead of strings. In your case, you seem to have UTF-8 which has a 3 byte (`EF BB BF`) BOM. You have to remove all three bytes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code will work only for [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), if your file.encoding property is different it won't remove the BOM
2. `ï`, `»` and `¿` are 3 characters in CP1252 therefore you need to replace `substring(1)` with `substring(3)`
3. In general it's better to stick to UTF-8 where possible so I would recommend amending your code as:

   ```
   def responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString().replace('\uFEFF', '')
   ```

   just make sure that JMeter's `file.encoding` property is set to `UTF-8`

More information:

- [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)